# JDialog não desenha os componentes no Java

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que irá executar um processamento logo, e quero que uma mensagem avisando que o processo está sendo executado fique na tela enquanto ele faz esse processamento. Tentei fazer com o `JOptionPane`, porém como ele é uma janela modal por padrão o processamento só irá continuar se for fechada. Então fiz uma janela simples com `JDialog`, porém após fazer a instância dela e dar um `.setVisible(true);` ela não desenha os componentes que possui. O processo por trás ocorre normalmente, e a janela fecha, então não está travando.

Segue código da janela:

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import java.awt.Font;

public class IndexAndo extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel lblIstoPodeLevar;
    private JLabel lblIndexandoAguarde;

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public IndexAndo() {
        setTitle("IR - Indexar");
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 150);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        {
            lblIstoPodeLevar = new JLabel("Isto pode levar alguns minutos.");
            lblIstoPodeLevar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        }
        {
            lblIndexandoAguarde = new JLabel("Executando indexa\u00E7\u00E3o, aguarde.");
            lblIndexandoAguarde.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        }
        GroupLayout gl_contentPanel = new GroupLayout(contentPanel);
        gl_contentPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(126, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblIndexandoAguarde)
                            .addGap(115))
                        .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblIstoPodeLevar)
                            .addGap(118))))
        );
        gl_contentPanel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(26)
                    .addComponent(lblIndexandoAguarde)
                    .addGap(9)
                    .addComponent(lblIstoPodeLevar)
                    .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        contentPanel.setLayout(gl_contentPanel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independentemente da janela ser modal ou não, se você tem um processo demorado a fazer você tem que colocá-lo **fora** do *event dispatcher thread*. Foi o clique de um botão ou algo assim que iniciou o processamento, certo? Se for, ele está rodando nesse thread, e enquanto ele não terminar o Swing não vai desenhar nada.

Crie um novo thread para seu processamento. Quando ele terminar, use o `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` para atualizar a janela de novo (isso é necessário pois a biblioteca Swing não é *thread-safe*):

```
void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Ou seja lá como você está iniciando seu processamento

    // Sua janela de progresso vem aqui. Não importa se é modal ou não.
    final JDialog janelaProgresso = new Indexando();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Seu processamento vem aqui

            // Ao terminar...
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    janelaProgresso.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

    janelaProgresso.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solução dada pelo [@mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10119/28595) é válida, mas creio que usar [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) seja mais adequado, pois essa classe foi feita justamente para trabalhar com paralelismo com a [EDT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), executando tarefas pesadas em uma thread a parte e depois até permitindo que se controle e exiba o progresso da atividade na tela, bem como possibilitando descobrir quando ela acabou e se acabou corretamente, sem ter que implementar nada de muito complexo.

Um exemplo de como poderia ser implementado:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){

    final JDialog janelaProgresso = new Indexando();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        publish();
        // aqui dentro você invoca a classe/metodo com a tarefa demorada
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Void> chunks) {
        janelaProgresso.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        janelaProgresso.setVisible(false);
    }

};
worker.execute();
```

[Neste link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) há mais referências sobre como essa classe funciona e como utilizá-la.