# Como fechar uma JDialog após terminar de executar uma Thread?

Tags: java, swing, thread

Tenho uma janela de configuração que abre na primeira execução do aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo. Após digitar os diretórios que o aplicativo irá rodar o usuário clica em salvar, alguns testes são executados e por fim roda uma Thread.

Eu gostaria de fazer com que após terminar a execução dessa Thread a janela de configuração fechasse sozinha, porém tentei executar `dispose()` e `setVisible()` e ela desaparece antes de executar a Thread.

```
// Evento para salvar os diretórios
btnSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        // Testa o campo com o diretório a ser indexado
        // Se está vazio
        if ((txtDirIndexado.getText().length() == 0 || Character
                .toString(txtDirIndexado.getText().charAt(0)).equals(
                        " "))) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(panel,
                            "O campo com o diretório a ser indexado não pode estar em branco.");
        } else if ((txtDirIndice.getText().length() == 0 || Character
                .toString(txtDirIndexado.getText().charAt(0)).equals(
                        " "))) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(panel,
                            "O campo com o diretório que guardará o índice não pode estar em branco.");

        } else {
            try {
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.defineFonte(txtDirIndexado.getText());
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.defineIndice(txtDirIndice.getText());
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.definePrimeiraExecucao(1);
                // Janela de aguardo
                final JDialog janelaProgresso = new IndexAndo();

                // Cria um novo processo e mostra a janela
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Indexador ind = new Indexador();
                        ind.iniciaIndexacao();

                        // Ao terminar fecha
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                janelaProgresso.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
                // Salva a data
                dispose();
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.defineIndiceUltAtualizacao();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Gera erro
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

O código na integra [pode ser acessado no git](https://github.com/matheusws/IR-IndexadorRepositorio/blob/master/srcs/Configuracao.java#L164).

Edição:

```
// Evento para salvar os direstórios
btnSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // Testa o campo com o diretório a ser indexado
        // Se está vazio
        if ((txtDirIndexado.getText().length() == 0 || Character
                .toString(txtDirIndexado.getText().charAt(0)).equals(
                        " "))) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(panel,
                            "O campo com o diretório a ser indexado não pode estar em branco.");
            // Se está vazio
        } else if ((txtDirIndice.getText().length() == 0 || Character
                .toString(txtDirIndexado.getText().charAt(0)).equals(
                        " "))) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(panel,
                            "O campo com o diretório que guardará o índice não pode estar em branco.");
            // Se o diretório existe
        } else {
            try {
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.defineFonte(txtDirIndexado.getText());
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.defineIndice(txtDirIndice.getText());
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.definePrimeiraExecucao(1);

                final JDialog janelaProgresso = new IndexAndo();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ProcessoIndexacao base = new ProcessoIndexacao();
                        base.start();
                        synchronized (base){
                            try {
                                base.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                janelaProgresso.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
                janelaProgresso.setVisible(true);
                // Salva a data
                ArquivoDeConfiguracao.defineIndiceUltAtualizacao();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Gera erro
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dispose();
    }
```

---

```
public class ProcessoIndexacao extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        synchronized (this){
            Indexador ind = new Indexador();
            ind.iniciaIndexacao();
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria importante você seguir esse conselho: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/3117). Assim mais pessoas se interessariam em lhe ajudar, pois nem todo mundo vai querer acessar o GitHUB para entender sua dúvida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vi seu código inteiro, mas se entendi bem seu problema você quer que uma Thread espere outra terminar para ser executada.

Basicamente o que você precisa é entender os conceitos de `wait()` e `notify()`.

Aqui tem um exemplo que eu implementei enquanto estudava para a prova de certificação Java:

```
public class WaitNotify {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //aqui você inicia uma nova Thread e manda ela rodar
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();
        //Thread atual deve ter o "lock" da thread b,isso é necessário para chamar o wait()
        synchronized(b) {
            System.out.print("Waiting for b to complete...");
            try {
                //aqui você diz que a Thread atual deve esperar a Thread b terminar
                b.wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    //aqui sua Thread começa a rodar
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {
                total += i;
                try {
                    //um temporizador para sua Thread não acabar na velocidade da luz!
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //faz uma frescura
                if(i%2 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            //Thread avisa que terminou sua execução para quem possui o lock de b
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Lembre-se que quando você roda uma classe que possui um método `main()` você está rodando uma thread que se chama *main*, assim como no exemplo acima, a thread *main* é uma thread como outra qualquer, então apenas a faça esperar uma outra thread até que ela chame o `notify()`.

Comment: Não consegui implementar 100%, quando rodo a Thread ela "trava" e nunca termina.

Comment: @Strokes você rodou o meu código ou implementou as threads no seu? Se for no seu poderia nos mostrar como ele ficou?

Comment: Implementei a sugestão adaptando com a minha necessidade. Postei na pergunta o novo código

Comment: @Strokes olhando me parece tudo certo.. vou ver melhor na hora do almoço, guentae

Comment: @Strokes fiz alguns testes aqui para tentar dar pau no código, e não consegui, daí me surgiram algumas dúvidas: o que você quer dizer com trava? Seu código entra em um loop infinito? Sua tela aparece e não responde? Teria como vc usar o debug para saber exatamente onde está o erro?

Comment: Então, pelo que eu percebi ele para ali no wait(). Ele abre a minha janelaProgresso mas não termina de desenhar, e fica nisso, consigo redimensionar ela e tudo mais. Mas o código não continua.

Comment: @Strokes você tem duas Thread, a primeira normalmente parará no wait mesmo, até que a outra chame o notify. Você chegou a ver se a segunda chega a executar o run? Se sim, onde ela trava? Outra coisa, vi que entre o `setVisible` true e false da janela tem apenas um método, será que ele não executa rápido demais não, ou então demorado demais e você acha que travou? Ultimo ponto de observação, será que você precisa mesmo de outra thread? Não tem como você chamar a janela dentro do seu primeiro código? Ou então pelo menos puxar o código de abrir e fechar a janela para a primeira thread.

Comment: Ele vai até o janelaProgresso.setVisible(true); e simplesmente para. Nada mais acontece!
Essa minha Thread tem relação com outra pergunta que fiz [aqui no SO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10114/jdialog-nao-modal-nao-desenha-os-componentes-no-java). Pois tenho a seguinte lógica: abre-se a janela de configuração, preenche e verifica o conteúdo, abre uma janela de "processando", executa o processo e fecha as duas janelas.

Comment: @Strokes no exemplo dele a instanciação da janela está fora da criação da nova thread, teria como voce modificar isso?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi o Java tá esperando a minha janelaProgresso ser fechada para continuar o código!

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, estou postando abaixo da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Galera, consegui resolver meu problema com o comando abaixo:

```
myJDialog.getOwner().dispose();
```

Segundo a documentação, esse método existe desde a versão 1.2 do java.

Comment: Esse comando vai fechar não só a dialog, mas a janela da qual ela foi chamada. Olhando a resposta aceita, não creio que isso resolveria o problema da pergunta.