# JTextArea recebe o append mas não exibe o texto

Tags: java, swing

Estou com problema ao utilizar um JTextArea. Eu preciso que a cada vez que acontece algo no meu sistema, uma informação é adicionada em tempo real. Porém, ele não aparece nada.

Já tentei usar o `setText()` e o `append()`, mas nenhum dos dois funcionou. Porém, se eu fazer isso aqui

```
JOptionpane.showMessageDialog(null, JtextArea.getText())
```

ele me retorna tudo que eu tinha escrito antes mas que  não estava aparecendo nele.
Já tentei usar `repaint()` também e nada.

Alguém já passou por isso?

---

Aqui vai um pedaço do código. Quando clico em um botão, ele tem essa chamada:

```
    if (!isStartServer()) {
        area.append("Iniciando servidor de aplicação...\n");
        Integer portaSocket = Integer.parseInt(tfPorta.getText());
        Integer limite = Integer.parseInt(tfLimite.getText());

        setStartServer(true);
        StartServidor s = new StartServidor(portaSocket, limite, this);
        new Thread(s).start();

        btStart.setText("Stop Server");
    }else{
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Dessa maneira, StartServidor se tornou uma Thread, que é geralmente onde vou escrever as mensagens no JtextArea. Quando eu não tinha esse "StartServidor" como uma Thread, ele não atualizava o JtextArea quando eu chamava o writeTextArea(String msg);

Código da StartServidor:

```
  public void run() {

    setPortaSocket(getPortaSocket());
    setLimite(getLimite());

    try {

        setServerSocket(new ServerSocket(getPortaSocket()));
        writeTextArea("Ouvindo a porta " + getPortaSocket() + "...");

        while (servidor.isStartServer()) {
            setSocketCliente(getServerSocket().accept());

            setUser(new User());
            getUser().setCliente(getSocketCliente());

            scanner = new Scanner(getUser().getCliente().getInputStream());

            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                getUser().setNome(scanner.nextLine());
            }

            writeTextArea(getUser().getNome() + " conectou-se.");

            if (!clientes.containsKey(getUser().getNome())) {
                clientes.put(getUser().getNome(), getUser());

                getUser().setIpComputador(getUser().getCliente().getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                getUser().setNomeComputador(getUser().getCliente().getInetAddress().getHostName());

                ServidorReadMessage read = new ServidorReadMessage(getUser(), this);
                new Thread(read).start();
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (getServerSocket() != null) {
                getServerSocket().close();
            }
            if (getSocketCliente() != null) {
                getSocketCliente().close();
            }
            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira, está escrevendo corretamente, porém, não sei se é a melhor maneira, não sei nem sei se é correto fazer assim. Por isso gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Já olhei a documentação e não diz nada sobre isso.

Comment: É possível que você tenha dois JTextArea no seu projeto, entretanto um foi adicionado ao JFrame e o outro não. Poderia nos mostrar seu código?

Comment: @Math
Quando eu clico em um botão, ele faz o seguinte: 

     `writeTextArea("Iniciando servidor...");`

Nada mais é do que isso aqui:
     `private void writeTextArea(String msg){
        area.append(msg+"\n");
    };`

Comment: e você tem certeza de que não chegou a instanciar dois objetos de JTextArea?

Comment: @Math
Tenho. Tenho apenas uma instância do JtextArea. O engraçado é que se eu dou um gextText pra mostrar em um Joptionpane por exemplo, ele mostra todo o texto.

Comment: @Math
http://www.guj.com.br/java/308638-jtextarea-recebe-o-append-mas-nao-exibe-o-texto-adicionado
Aqui ele destacou melhor. Mas estou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Li o link que você passou. Infelizmente lá ele não deu a solução né? Enfim.. Seu código é muito grande? Pois acredito que disponibilizando-o ficaria mais fácil te ajudar. Talvez se você fizer um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ajuda também.

Comment: Seu text area está dentro de um `JScrollPane` tal como o exemplo linkado? O problema permanece se você tirar ele de lá? E o seu modelo - `Document` - é o padrão? (se você não sabe do que eu estou falando, então sim, é o padrão) P.S. Concordo com o Math, coloque um exemplo completo, pois somente as informações postadas parecem ser insuficientes para entender o problema.

Comment: A propósito, você está fazendo processamento pesado no *Event Dispatcher Thread*? (ex.: ao clicar em um botão, o próprio `actionPerformed` desse botão começa um loop que demora pra terminar) Se a resposta for sim, então está explicado seu problema... Veja [essa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10119/215) em uma outra pergunta para mais detalhes (o contexto é diferente, mas a causa raiz seria a mesma).

Comment: @math
Atualizei o código ali em cima, se poderes dar uma olhada. Agradeço.

Comment: @mgibsonbr
Atualizei o código ali em cima. Antes de eu colocar "StartServidor" como uma Thread, dentro dessa classe ele tem basicamente um while(true) dentro dela pra aceitar conexões no socket. Será por isso então? Mas porque depois que implementei Runnable no "StartServidor" ele atualizava o JtexArea corretamente? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar Exatamente! Vou postar uma resposta com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Quando clico em um botão, ele tem essa chamada:

Todo código executado em resposta a um clique em botão executa na [*Event Dispatcher Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Esse thread é usado para praticamente tudo o que faz interface com a biblioteca Swing. Desse modo, se você tem um código:

```
void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Código
}
```

Enquanto esse código não terminar de executar o Swing não vai fazer mais nada (repintar telas, atualizar componentes, etc).

> Dessa maneira, StartServidor se tornou uma Thread, que é geralmente onde vou escrever as mensagens no JtextArea. Quando eu não tinha esse "StartServidor" como uma Thread, ele não atualizava o JtextArea quando eu chamava o writeTextArea(String msg);

De fato, antes de você mover seu código para uma thread separada, o loop que aguardava por novas conexões executava no *Event Dispatcher Thread*. Isso significa que o `actionPerformed` **nunca retornava!** Ele ficava parado, esperando as conexões dos soquetes, e com isso o Swing não fazia mais nada. Quando você tentava usar `setText` no JTextArea, ele atualizava seu modelo (`Document`) mas não mexia na visão. Assim, se você fizesse:

```
area.getText();
```

Ele te daria o conteúdo atualizado (pois o modelo *foi* atualizado), mas se você olhasse pra caixa de texto na tela você só veria o valor antigo (pois quem atualiza a tela é o *Event Dispatcher Thread*, e ele está parado esperando seu código terminar de executar).

> Dessa maneira, está escrevendo corretamente, porém, não sei se é a melhor maneira, não sei nem sei se é correto fazer assim.

Sim, essa maneira é correta. Mas a melhor maneira seria usar um `SwingWorker`: um tipo de thread específico para tarefas iniciadas via Swing. Aqui tem [uma documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) (em inglês) descrevendo seu uso e seus benefícios. Mas se quiser continuar fazendo do jeito que está, não tem o menor problema.

**Detalhe Importante:** a grande maioria dos métodos da biblioteca Swing **não são** *thread-safe*. Isso significa que - se você precisa alterar algum componente a partir de um outro thread (inclusive o *main thread*), você deve fazê-lo [através de um dos métodos especiais do `SwingUtilities`](http://www.guj.com.br/java/131504-swingutilitiesinvokelater). Exemplo:

```
// Seu thread (ou main thread)

/* area.setText("texto"); // ERRADO */
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        area.setText("texto"); // Certo
    }
});

// Event Dispatcher Thread

area.setText("texto"); // Certo
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Não conhecia essa parte do SweingUtilities e SwingWorker, aí tenho algumas dúvidas. Quanto ao porque ele não atualizava o JtexArea, putz, muito bem explico.
Por exemplo, se eu não quisesse colocar o StartServidor rodando numa Thread separado, eu colocaria todo o meu código dentro do SwingUtilities.invokeLater() para poder obter o mesmo resultado?

Comment: @CristianoBombazar Não, o `invokeLater` faz o contrário: pega um código que estaria numa thread qualquer e coloca no *Event Dispatcher Thread*. Se você **já está** no EDT, não faz sentido usar esse método (e não adiantaria nada também, pois ele iria bloquear do mesmo jeito). Tem que ser num Thread separado mesmo - ou um normal, que nem você fez, ou um `SwingWorker`. De um jeito ou de outro está OK.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código do método `writeTextArea(String msg)` poderia estar assim:

```
private void writeTextArea(String msg){
    area.setText(area.getText()+msg+"\n");
    area.repaint();
}
```

Basicamente ele define o texto do seu JTextArea para qualquer texto que já estava dentro, adiciona a mensagem e renderiza novamente o JTextArea.
Se não der certo, não faço a mínima ideia do que seja, sendo que a própria JVM deveria renderizar novamente o componente se ele foi modificado.

Comment: Oi. Obrigado pro responder.
Ele já estava com repaint, mas não funcionou, então removi. Irei postar um exemplo que fiz bem simples, não do meu código, mas que provavelmente, vai ser o mesmo problema que todo mundo vai enfrentar. Desculpe se não estou postando corretamente as mensagens aqui no tópico, ainda estou me acostumando com o fórum.